# MFC - How to get all process id related (they are all process of one program)

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm working with Visual Studio 2010, building MFC app.

I have a question: how to get all Process ID of one program.

Example: I run VMware Workstation program and all process of them are: vmware-unity-helper.exe, vwware.exe.

Now I want to get id of them. How can I do that? Thankss

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do that unless VMWare publishes info about its processes somewhere.

If you know the names of the processes, you can scan all started processes ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686832(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and find those that you need. The number of processes is from 100 to 1000. This means that iteration will not take too long.

Comment: Thanks. Seem i have to get all process then got all process related VMware.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is, iterate over all processes and search processes with name containing *vmware* 
It shows how to get process Ids and name. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work so correctly. I tried it last few hours :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no exist way to achieve your requirement.
For your vmware example, you can enumerate all process and match them name with "vmware",  but there some other program that do not match the rule, (ex. if you want to find Visual Studio process, its name is devenv.exe, they are not any relation.).

One way for your aim. You can refer below information.

- Prepare a predefined configure file.
- Research the program interesting, and find their related process name, use a `map` to store into configure file.
- When you want to get the process id, query your configure file and get related process name, iterate all running process and match them.
- You need to maintain your configure file when program change its process or you want to add new program support.

Comment: You're right. Still have problem with some programs like Visual Studio. So can not catch all process of it by name. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If the processes all contain a "base" name of some sort, a regular expression could be used.

Else, if you are looking for the child/parent connections between processes (which process launched which process); then a combination of the WIN32 [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Process32First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should do the trick. Process32First returns data in a PROCESSENTRY32 strtucture that contains a PID th32ParentProcessID for the parent.